# Recyclerview GridlayoutManager OnBindViewHolder position & getAdapterPosition() is wrong when scrolling

Tags: android

I am using Recyclerview with GridLayoutManager to view multiple viewholders with different types and different SpanSize:

```
listsLayoutManager.setSpanCount(6);
listsLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (adapter.getItemViewType(position) == VODsGridRVAdapter.TYPE_TITLE || adapter.getItemViewType(position) == VODsGridRVAdapter.TYPE_HEADER)
                return 6;
            return 1;
        }
    });
```

Here is the getItemViewType method:

```
 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    return dataList.get(position - 1).isTitle() ? TYPE_TITLE : TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

where position 0 is always for the header.

When scrolling the view, the onBindViewHolder gives wrong position and the getAdapterPosition is doing that so.
is there any solution for this problem but to use         `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 36 hours of debugging and trying, I was able to solve this problem by removing the `adapter.setHasStableIds(true);` line from my Activity.